# Is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ that is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ necessarily open?

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, such that $A$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Is $A$ open in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. This is a special case of the theorem of [invariance of domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain).